# Eclipse closing as soon as Workspace is loaded

Tags: eclipse

My eclipse closing as soon as possible when workspace is completed then it's closing automatically and it's showing below error in configuration folder of eclipse. So tell me what i have to do to fix this problem in my windows-7 PC.

```
!SESSION 2014-10-13 10:24:02.537 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 4 0 2014-10-13 10:24:58.638
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The profile is currently in use.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.lockProfile(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:807)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.setProperty(ProfileSynchronizer.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.synchronize(ProfileSynchronizer.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.synchronize(Activator.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The profile is currently in use.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.lockProfile(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:807)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.setProperty(ProfileSynchronizer.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.synchronize(ProfileSynchronizer.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.synchronize(Activator.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-10-13 10:26:29.290
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.createHandle(Composite.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createHandle(Decorations.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.createHandle(Shell.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.createWidget(Scrollable.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createWidget(Decorations.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.createShell(Window.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.prompt(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like one instance of eclipse is already running on your machine. Go to task manager and end the already running eclipse process and try to invoke eclipse again.

Answer (score 0):

You are running an eclipse product(`org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product`).

1. Open your product file in **Product configuration Editor** go to **Dependencies** tab click on **Add Required** button.
2. Go the Run/debug configuration of your product and go to **Plug-ins** tab and click on **Add Required Plugins** button then try to debug it.

Also refer [Eclipse Product Deployment Problems](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html#exportproblems).